# pdftooltip over gls entry prevents the first use from working

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra, pdfcomment

I've added a tool-tip to show the acronyms long entry with the `pdfcomment` and `glossaries`
package. However, with the tool-tip enabled, the first glossary appearance does not show.
I though the issue might be tied to using `\glsentrylong` and perhaps `pdftooltip` expanded it first which could have triggered the `glossaries` entry's internal "first-usage flag", but I dispelled that hunch by testing it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\usepackage{pdfcomment}
%%% these command make the first use not work
\let\oldgls\gls
\RenewDocumentCommand{\gls}{ O{} m O{} }{%
    \pdftooltip{\oldgls[#1]{#2}[#3]}{\glsentrylong{#2}}% tries glsentrytext, glsfmtlong
}%

\let\oldglspl\glspl
\RenewDocumentCommand{\glspl}{ O{} m O{} }{%
    \pdftooltip{\oldglspl[#1]{#2}[#3]}{\glsentrylong{#2}}%
}%
%%%%%%
\makeglossaries

\newacronym{hw}{HW}{Hello World}
\newacronym{fb}{FB}{Foo Bar}

\begin{document}
    \glsentrylong{hw} % when the pdf tooltip commands are commented out, it still shows the long use?

    \gls{hw}, \gls{fb} ---first use

    \gls{hw}, \gls{fb} ---second use

     \printglossary

\end{document}
```

Desired:
[image]

Issue:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking if the glossary entry is used, and only producing the tool-tip if it has appeared previous fixes the problem--this should be fine as you only need to see the tool-tip when the acronym appears. I suspect internally `pdftooltip` expands the gls entry but does not print it (maybe to determine the area of the link?), which would increment the usage counter behind the scenes.

```
\let\oldgls\gls
\RenewDocumentCommand{\gls}{ O{} m  O{}}{%
    \ifglsused{#2}{%
        \pdftooltip{\oldgls[#1]{#2}[#3]}{\glsentrylong{#2}}% tries glsentrytext, glsfmtlong
    }{%
        \oldgls[#1]{#2}[#3]
    }%
}%
```